# Why table with only 6 rows taking around 20 seconds to return the results in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have a table with only 6 rows but when i am querying a simple select on that table "select * from table_name" it is taking 20 seconds to return the recordes. I need to understand why it is taking so much time and what can be done to imporve it.

Few information related to table which one can use for answering:
1.) Only Not null constraints are present on two columns of the table. No other constraint.
2.) No index or partitions on the table.
3.) Attached is the execution plan for the table.

Explain Plan Image:

[image: Explain Plan Image]

Comment: did you test the connection to the database host? Maybe there's a network issue that causes the latency

Comment: Cost is quite high, is it not? What is that TABLE_NAME, actually? Maybe some complex view? Over a database link? What does explain plan say?

Comment: @Littlefoot is correct. The cost is too high, it means that the segment is pretty big.

Comment: @procra This is hapeening for past few days. All other tables are getting queried properly apart from this one.

Comment: @Littlefoot i have attaced the screenshot of explain plan in the question. It is not a complex view and neither any database link is involved. Just quering a table in a schema.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the segment of the table was extended (a lot of rows were inserted) and then most of rows were deleted.

Read about `alter table move update indexes` and about `alter table shrink space`:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/alter-table-shrink-space-online